# How can i implement orthogonality constraint on the columns of weight matrix in the hidden layers of a neural network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to train a neural network with orthogonality constraint on the columns of the weight matrix of the hidden layers i.e the weight matrix learned should have orthogonal columns. How to do this in keras ?